# How can I replace everything within a string but a group of substrings?

Tags: regex, ruby, gsub

I'm trying to replace everything in my `input` string that is not `/str|con|dex|wis|int|cha/`, but I'm unsure of the correct syntax. I've tried the following:

```
input.gsub(/[^str|con|dex|wis|int|cha]/, '')
input.gsub(/[^str,con,dex,wis,int,cha]/, '')
input.gsub(/[^str|^con|^dex|^wis|^int|^cha]/, '')
input.gsub(/[^str,^con,^dex,^wis,^int,^cha]/, '')
```

The following `input`s:

```
+4cha
+2 strength
-3wisdom
+1asdfdexasdf
```

should return:

```
cha
str
wis
dex
```

To be clear, I'm only expecting one occurrence of a substring within `input`.

Comment: Perhaps use a capturing group to match all the options or match any char and replace with group 1 `(str|con|dex|wis|int|cha)|.` https://regex101.com/r/Wd2UBc/1 but matching instead might be easier.

Comment: what should be the output if there's more than one match, for example `+4cha34con-42` ?

Comment: @Sundeep I've already accounted for that in a previous part of my code. There will always be only one substring present

Comment: @The fourth bird I'm unfamiliar with capturing groups. How would the syntax work for this? (Like this? `input.gsub(/(str|con|dex|wis|int|cha)|./, $1)`)

Comment: I think it will look like this `puts("+4cha".gsub(/(str|con|dex|wis|int|cha)|./, '\1'))`

Comment: When asked for clarification (regarding multiple matches, for example), please edit your question rather than elaborate in a comment. Questions should be self-contained. For one, not all readers read all comments.

Comment: Do you not want simply `input[/str|con|dex|wis|int|cha/]`? If so, why would you select an answer that uses `gsub` with a capture group?

Comment: Fixed my question. Thanks for the tip, Cary. I selected that answer before 3limin4t0r posted his.

Comment: In future consider waiting longer before selecting an answer. Most members wait at least a couple of hours, some wait much longer, allowing then-sleeping members a chance to answer. The point is that there is no rush to select an answer. Quick selections can discourage the posting of what might be better answers, answers that sometimes show the selected answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your only expecting one occurrence you could use the [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method:

```
input = input[/str|con|dex|wis|int|cha/]
```

This gives you the first occurrence or `nil` if it doesn't match. If you'd like a default empty string simply change it to:

```
input = input[/str|con|dex|wis|int|cha/] || ''
```

Comment: Thank you for giving the obvious answer. I re-read the question, comments and answers several times, thinking I must be missing something before concluding that I wasn’t.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to match everything that's *not* that regex. You need to match everything that *is*.

```rb
inputs = [
  "+4cha",
  "+2 strength",
  "-3wisdom",
  "+1asdfdexasdf",
]
inputs.map do |input|
  matches = input.match(/str|con|dex|wis|int|cha/)
  matches[0] if matches
end.compact
# => ["cha", "str", "wis", "dex"]
```

So given an input string, you check if it matches any of str, con, dex, wis, int, or cha. If it does, you return the match. If it doesn't, you return nil.

Then, `compact` removes all `nil`s from your array. Leaving you with an array of your matches.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this regex way https://regex101.com/r/bFwkIZ/1 to get only **first** group that matched.

```
re = /(?:.*?)(str|con|dex|wis|int|cha)(?:.*?)/m
str = '+4cha
+2 strength
-3wisdom
+1asdfdexasdf'

# Print the match result
str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What function do the question marks have in your example? I still have a lot to learn about regular expressions.

Comment: the preceding `?:` make that group to non-capture and later `?` means match only zero or one preceding character, see the regex101 link they provide more detailed explanation on the right side

Comment: One more thing I'm not a ruby guy so the code snippet you may need to change as per your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58879334/how-can-i-replace-everything-within-a-string-but-a-group-of-substrings?noredirect=1#comment104025927_58879334):

```
>> '+4cha'.gsub(/(str|con|dex|wis|int|cha)|./, '\1')
=> "cha"
>> '+2 strength'.gsub(/(str|con|dex|wis|int|cha)|./, '\1')
=> "str"
>> '-3wisdom'.gsub(/(str|con|dex|wis|int|cha)|./, '\1')
=> "wis"
>> '+1asdfdexasdf'.gsub(/(str|con|dex|wis|int|cha)|./, '\1')
=> "dex"
```

When two or more alternations match from same index, the precedence is left to right in order of declaration. So, whenever the capture group above matches, the left alternation wins and the string gets preserved via backreference. If the capture group doesn't match, `.` will match and `\1` will be empty.